# How to pass data to another file?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class apidata extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
      axios.get(`https://url`)
        .then(res => {
          const items = res.data;

        })
    }
}
```

How to pass the `items` json data to parent class file that import this class ?

Comment: So you want to pass `this.state.items` to another component?

Comment: yes in props or state

Comment: What is the issue? Please clarify your problem. Normally, you just pass data as props. Is there any condition you can t do that?

Comment: You can only pass props from parent to child component. So your component structure needs to accommodate this top down flow.  Explicitly passing state to other components requires a state management library.

Comment: No conditions, I just looking for an example how to pass `items` to another file that import this class

Comment: Your Q is not clear yet. Please provide an example.

Comment: Why don't you just make this API fetch inside the component you need it? There's not much detail to go off of here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a method live on the parent that expects the `items` and does something with it. Then, pass it down to the `ApiData` component as props. Here's an example:

```
class Parent extends Component {
  handleItems(items) {
    // Do something
  }

  render() {
    return <ApiData handleItems={this.handleItems} />;
  }
}

class ApiData extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://url`)
      .then(res => {
        const items = res.data;
        this.props.handleItems(items);
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: is there a way to pass the data without using render() ?

Comment: You mentioned you wanted to pass data from `ApiData` to its parent. In React, a parent renders a child.